# Siesta handling multiple requests

Tags: swift, siesta-swift

I have a loop where I POST requests to the server:

```
for (traineeId, points) in traineePointsDict {  
    // create a new point
    let parameters: NSDictionary = [
        "traineeId": "\(traineeId)",
        "numPoints": points,
        "exerciseId": "\(exerciseId)"
    ]

    DataManager.sharedInstance.api.points.request(.POST, json: parameters).success { data in
        if data.json["success"].int == 1 {
            self.pointCreated()
        } else {
            self.pointFailToCreate()
        }
    }.failure { error in
        self.pointFailToCreate()
    }
}
```

The problem is that for some reason the last request fails and I am guessing that this is due to posting too many requests to the server at the same time.

Is there a way to chain these requests so they wait for the one before to complete before executing the next?

I have been looking at PromiseKit, but I don't really know how to implement this and I am looking for a quick solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siesta does not control how requests are queued or how many requests run concurrently. You have two choices:

1. control it on the app side, or
2. control it in the network layer.

I’d investigate option 2 first. It gives you less fine-grained control, but it give you more robust options on the cheap and is less prone to mistakes. If you are using `URLSession` as your networking layer (which is Siesta’s default), then investigate whether the `HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost` property of `URLSessionConfiguration` does what you need. (Here are [some examples](http://bustoutsolutions.github.io/siesta/api/Protocols/NetworkingProviderConvertible.html) of passing custom configuration to Siesta.)

If that doesn’t work for you, a simple version of #1 is to use a completion handler to chain the requests:

```
func chainRequests(_ queue: [ThingsToRequest])
  guard let thing = queue.first else { return }
  params = makeParamsFor(thing)
  resource.request(.POST, json: params)
    .onSuccess {
      ...
    }.onFailure {
      ...
    }.onCompletion { _ in
      chainRequests(queue[1 ..< queue.count])
    }
}
```

Note that you can attach multiple overlapping handlers to the same request, and they’re called in the order you attached them. Note also that Siesta guarantees that the `completion` block is *always* called, no matter the outcome. This means that each request will result in calls to either closures 1 & 3 or closures 2 & 3. That’s why this approach works.